# Manipulating two parameters of a plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am wondering if it is possible to manipulate/animate two (or three) parameters in a plot. I would imagine this would work, but doesn't:

```
waves[a_, b_, c_] := Sin[a b + c] Cos[a + b];
Animate[Plot3D[waves[a, b, c], {a, -2, 2}], {b, 0, 5}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

I would like to manipulate/animate the parameters `b` and `c`. Is this possible? If so, what would the code look like?

Comment: Remove the '3D' from `Plot3D` as your equation is only a 2 dimensional equation. If you have 3 parameters you can either plot in 2D and animate 2 parameters, or plot in 3D and animate a single parameter. `Plot3D` is expecting to see 2 variables that it can vary along 2 different axes, but it only sees `a` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @MassDefect:

```
waves[a_, b_, c_] := Sin[a b + c] Cos[a + b];
Animate[
   Plot[waves[a, b, c], {a, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
   {b, 0, 5}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

[image]